# How do I log the request body (req.body) in the msg object using express-winston?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, winston

I'm trying to log `{{ req.body }}` via `express-winston`'s `msg:` object.

I've already whitelisted the body using `expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');` but it is still not present in the log.

```js
export const accessLogger = (router: Router) => {
    expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');
    router.use(expressWinston.logger({
        level: "info";
        format: winston.format.simple(),
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console()
        ],
        meta: false,
        metaField: null!,
        msg: "HTTP {{ req.method }} {{ req.url }} {{ req.body }}",
        expressFormat: true
    }));
}
```

Using:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"test": "value"}' http://localhost:someport'
```

Currently looks like the below in the log:

```
info: POST / 200 1ms
```

Should look something like:

```
info: POST / 200 1ms {\"test\": \"value\"}
```

If I enable `meta` using `meta:true` I know & see it's there:

```
info: POST / 200 1ms {"req":{"url":"/","headers":{"host":"localhost:someport","user-agent":"curl/7.63.0","accept":"application/json","content-length":"17","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},"method":"POST","httpVersion":"1.1","originalUrl":"/","query":{},"body":{"{\"test\": \"value\"}":""}},"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":1}
```

But I don't want the entire meta filling my log for now.

Comment: https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` is by default not included because it will often contain things that shouldn't be logged like passwords, so be sure you want to do it before you do.

Since you have now been warned, you can add it by adding

`expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');`

somewhere after loading `expressWinston` and before `app.using` `expressWinston.logger`.

Comment: SEE MY CODE FOR HELP: 
router.use(expressWinston.logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({filename: 'log.json'})
  ],
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.json()
  )
}));
expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.write('This is a normal request, it should be logged to the console too');
  res.end();
});